# CORS error for NODEJS server running on the same machine as domain

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, cors

I have a NodeJS server running on my machine, and I am trying to access it with ajax from a website running on the same machine. I have getting a cross domain error though:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/games. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I have access a different api on this machine, running with php, which the address is 
http://localhost/games.

My thinking is that because the nodejs server is running on a different port to apache that is causing the cross domain issue?

Any insight would be great, im new to api development and not sure where to go from here.

It has been suggested to me that I should try use JSONP, but im not sure if this is technically needed, since the api is running on the same machine?

Comment: *"My thinking is that because the nodejs server is running on a different port to apache that is causing the cross domain issue"* Bingo. you need to abide by the same origin policy using CORS. research CORS. jsonp is also an option, however i usually prefer cors where possible.

Comment: Is there a way to make it run on the same port? port 80 I believe?

Comment: Yes, if you have your webserver (apache? iis? nginx?) reverse proxy it to a folder on the existing domain.

Comment: Apache running on XAMP if it makes much of a difference

Comment: Should be possible. Basically, in apache you would reverse proxy all requests to `/api` to your node server (`http://localhost:3000`). Now you can request from your node server's root by requesting `http://localhost/api`. I've done it with nginx and iis, but not apache.

Comment: Sounds like the best solution tbh, since I cant use JSONP because I need POST requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74664/discussion-between-user2254372-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to be able to send POST requests, your only options are:

- Implement CORS
- Reverse Proxy
- php proxy (or whatever language you are using for serving html pages)

The easiest would be to implement CORS if you are using express. Most of the work is done for you, all you would need to do is include the cors module and attach it as middleware.

Reverse proxy is the next solution to look at. What it does is it takes all requests to a given domain or domain/folder and reroutes them to the specified domain, in this case your node server running on a different port. For example, you would route all requests to `http://localhost/api` to `http://localhost:3000`. Research `Reverse Proxy` for the webserver you are using.

The third solution would be to have the webserver serving html also send requests to the node server. I consider this to be a bit too hacky for my tastes because the above two solutions are easy to implement and don't add additional code to the html webserver. However, if you didn't own the target webserver, this would be the only option if the target webserver didn't support CORS.

Comment: I have made this the accepted answer, as it seems to be the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

An origin is defined as a combination of URI scheme, hostname, and port number so you're indeed breaking the same origin policy performing a XMLHttpRequest  from http://localhost to http://localhost:3000

I'm not very familiar with nodejs but I see five options:

- Obviously the easiest thing would be run everything on the same port, not sure if this is possible or not on your scenario.
- Use JSONP (only valid for GET requests)
- Implement CORS headers (it has some compatibilities issues with IE <= 9 + [other corner case anomalies](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2559-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-may-block-cors-ajax-options-requests.htm))
- Implement a proxy to always communicate to http://localhost from client. Let the proxy deal with http://localhost:3000 and return response to client.
- Use an alternative to perform cross domain request as [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain)

Comment: I need to be able to perform POST requests also, so JSONP isnt a valid solution :/ I will look into how to proxy it, or implement CORS headers.